# Поиск в elasticsearch с/без "not_analyzed"

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

Вот есть такой вопрос, можно ли при поиске в elasticsearch поставить опцию "not_analyzed" , или может есть способ как то создать шаблон на сервере и использовать его, просто хочу в по одному и тому-же индексу искать как с "not_analyzed" так и без него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы представить одно поле как с/без "not_analyzed" нужно использовать [Multi Field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html)
Это полезно при сортировке по полю, которое одновременно используется в полнотекстовом поиске.

Multifield mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "product": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "russian",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                         "type": "string",
                         "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример запроса в котором используется поле name и subfield (подполе) name.raw:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "смартфон"
        }
    },
    "sort": "name.raw"
}
```

Comment: А при этом raw заполняется сам или надо добавлять данные и в raw тоже ???

Comment: raw заполнять не нужно, за вас все делает elasticsearch. Отправляется только {"name": "Название чего-то"}. "raw" - это произвольное название, с таким же успехом можно назвать подполе по-другому, например sort.